# Returning certain amount of documents from elasticsearch query in java

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am trying to limit the document size returned by my query.i want lets say 10 documents back only,any my query normally displays 22,how would i go buy setting a limit for the returned output. i am aware i can just limit the list size by creating a list and adding to that list however i want to do it on the query level.
My Query:  Thanks in advance :)

```
ueryBuilder raceGenderQuery = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
            .must(termQuery("lep_etg_desc", "indian"))
            .must(termQuery("lep_gen_desc", "male"));

    Set<String> suburbanLocationSet = new HashSet<String>();
    suburbanLocationSet.add("queensburgh");
    suburbanLocationSet.add("umhlanga");
    suburbanLocationSet.add("tongaat");
    suburbanLocationSet.add("phoenix");
    suburbanLocationSet.add("shallcross");
    suburbanLocationSet.add("balito");

    //Build the necessary location query.
    QueryBuilder locationQuery = QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(termsQuery("lep_suburb_home", suburbanLocationSet));

    //Combine all Queries so that its filtered to get exact results.
    FilteredQueryBuilder finalSearchQuery = QueryBuilders.filteredQuery(QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(raceGenderQuery).must(locationQuery), FilterBuilders.boolFilter().must(FilterBuilders.rangeFilter("lep_age").gte(25).lte(45)).must(FilterBuilders.rangeFilter("lep_max_income").gte(25000).lte(45000)));

    //Run Query through elasticsearch iterating through documents in the traceps index for query matches.
    List<Leads> finalLeadsList = new ArrayList<Leads>();
    for (Leads leads : this.leadsRepository.search(finalSearchQuery)) {
        finalLeadsList.add(leads);
    }
```

Comment: where are you settings the size of the result for the query?

Comment: Hi Elisah,i am not setting it anywhere as i would like to know where i can set the size,i am using the spring data start elasticsearch plugin in a spring boot application..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
    SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch().setSearchType(SearchType.QUERY_THEN_FETCH).setSize(10).setQuery(finalSearchQuery).execute().get
```

You have to use `QUERY_THEN_FETCH` for it to return exactly `size` results because otherwise it gets `size` results from each shard.

Comment: ok cool,1 more question ,how do i match the response to my document "Leads" ?